# JavaScript Print Specific Area with Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to print a specific div with the css included. I have tried the code below but when I add the css line in, it prints a **blank page** no content at all. Removing the css line prints the **page without any css**.

```
 function PrintElem(elem){
    Popup($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
 }

 function Popup(data){

 var mywindow = window.open();
 mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
 mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/casestudy.css" type="text/css">');
 mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/side-menu.css" type="text/css">');

 mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
 mywindow.document.write(data);
 mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

 mywindow.print();
}
```

How can I fix this issue. I would like to print with all the css included.

Comment: is the `<link href="./css/casestudy.css">` correct? Can you make sure?

Comment: Use a print stylesheet, that removes everything else but the element you want to print. Then you don't need to open any additional windows.

Comment: @VladNeacsu yes. I checked it multiple times.

Comment: @CBroe any chance you can provide an example?

Comment: No, print stylesheets are something you can go read up on.

Answer (score 0):

you can try css

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
        body * { visibility: hidden; }
        .printme* { visibility: visible; }
        .printme { position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 30px; }
    }
</style>
```